# how to print content properly with react

Tags: html, node.js, json, reactjs

I have react web application and I want to print data from a JSON file.
I have the data written inside the JSON file like:

"Hi, me again :)\n\nOver the past few weeks,"...

when I'm trying to print this content (which described in type with field content: string) it ignores all the \n and prints the content in a not appropriate way

using:

```
<p className="content">{object.content}</p>
```

how can I print it pretty? and limits the content to the size of the area it prints inside?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"not appropriate"*, but line breaks in HTML need to be `<br>`, not `\n`.

Comment: the content saved inside the json file with \n .. I need to translate is and show it in nice styling. (with the line space and inside the content area)

Comment: For *"line space"* you'll need to swap in HTML line breaks. As for *"inside the content area"* it's unclear what the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this if you create lines from the content. And then you end each line with: `<br />`

For examle:

```
export default function App() {
  const content = "Hi, me again :)\n\nOver the past few weeks,";
  const lines = content.split("\n");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {lines.map(line => (
        <>
          <div>{line}</div>
          <br />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the examle:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-shape-t0tdk

You can also solve it with [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html). But its dangerous you know. :)